# Unable to create a new Word Add-In project

Tags: visual-studio, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I've been trying to create a new Word Add-In project in my machine but for some reason the scaffolding of a new project always fails:

[image: first error msg]

[image: second error msg]

The error msg says `Unable to find version '2.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotnetCompilerPlatform'`.

What I get is a broken reference:

[image: broken ref]

That can be fixed by downloading the package using the Nuget Package Manager. However, I don't get any of the files generated via scaffolding. Any ideas?

I'm having problems running other pre-existing Add-in projects and I have a hunch that this scaffolding error is related to the other issues.

The same happens for any Add-In projects(Word, Excel, etc). I have no issues with other non-Addin projects.

This is a machine with a brand new installation of VS Enterprise 2017. I've already tried re-installing VS completely but had no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: If I read this article correctly [managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders), once you install it, you should not get that error again. VS should just copy it to the local package folder. Do you have non-standard settings for the package manager? There's some troubleshooting info in that article.

Comment: @RickKirkham I can confirm I have the right version of the package in my local package folder, but the scaffolding still fails - https://imgur.com/a/jfTJqGl . I didn't change any Nuget-related settings.